# Issue with running more than one topology on storm cluster

Tags: cloud, bigdata, apache-storm

It is not possible to run more than one topology on the same cluster.
All topologies are registered fine, I can see them in the UI, but only the first topology runs.
No workers,executors,tasks are allocated for the other topologies.

```
**storm.yaml:**

storm.local.dir: "/var/storm"
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "SERVER_IP"

#
nimbus.host: "HOST_IP"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
supervisor.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
```

Comment: Did you try a "storm rebalance mytopo -n 4"? (with 4 workers for mytopo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

increase the number of ports in `supervisor.slots.ports`. now it has only 4 ports (6700 to 6703) means only 4 workers will run on that supervisor machine.
If you have 4 topologies, each with 10 workers, then you have to add 40 ports (means from 6700 to 6739).

Answer (score 1):

You can also set conf.setNumberOfWorker(); That many workers will be allocated to your topology out of those available worker processes.